# Allow using inexact component type signatures for props when optional in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there any way to allow the acceptance of components with arguments with optional types when those types are not in the signature?
I keep getting this pattern and feel that Typescript should know better.

Ex:

```
type Comp1Props = {a: string, b?: string}
type NeededProps = {a: string}

// May be my component or out of a library..
const Comp1 = ({a, b="SomeText"}:Comp1Props)=>...

// I need this to work based more easily
const MultiUseWrapperComponent = ({Component: FC<NeededProps>})=>...

// In JSX
// Causes error due to OPTIONAL field b on Comp1 
<MultiUseWrapperComponent Component={Comp1} />
```

Are there Typescript settings to fix this behavior or some type workarounds aside from remapping the component like this?

```
// causes prop change from new function constructed in update
<MultiUseWrapperComponent Component={p=><Comp1 {...p}/>} />

// Unclean
const Comp = useCallback(p=><Comp1 {...p}/>,[])
...
<MultiUseWrapperComponent Component={Comp} />
```

I feel like this should fix it and it doesn't either:

```
type NeededProps = {a: string, [x:string]:any}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a playground/sandbox link with this example setup, will be able to gauge it better

Comment: I tried to make your code into a minimal example but got no type errors: https://tsplay.dev/NDkj8w Please create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 that demonstrates the errors your getting.

Comment: I recreated in a Sandbox and got no error. Looks like it's probably a config.